# Rascal LSP Typechecker

Tags: rascal, liskov-substitution-principle

I am trying out figure out Rascal LSP and I have it working fine but I want to enable the TypeChecker but I can’t figure out how to construct a Builder object to pass to *builder* function from the code below?

```
@synopsis{Each kind of service contributes the implementation of one (or several) IDE features.}
data LanguageService
  = parser(Parser parser)
  | summarizer(Summarizer summarizer
    , bool providesDocumentation = true
    , bool providesDefinitions = true
    , bool providesReferences = true
    , bool providesImplementations = true)
  | outliner(Outliner outliner)
  | completer(Completer completer)
  | builder(Builder builder)
  | lenses(LensDetector detector)
  | inlayHinter(InlayHinter hinter)
  | executor(CommandExecutor executor)
  | documenter(Documenter documenter)
  | definer(Definer definer)
  | referrer(Referrer reference)
  | implementer(Implementer implementer)
  ;


set[LanguageService] aliasesContributions() = {
  parser(parser(#start[Program])) 
    build(“alias", checkAliases)// How do I construct this?
   outliner(aliasesOutliner),
   summarizer(aliasesSummarizer, providesImplementations = false)
 };

Tree checkAliases(Tree input){
  model = aliasesTModelFromTree(input); // your function that collects & solves
  types = getFacts(model);
  
 return input[@messages={*getMessages(model)}]
       [@hyperlinks=getUseDef(model)]
       [@docs=(l:"<prettyAType(types[l])>" | l <- types)]; 
}
```

I have gone through all the examples I can find but I haven't seen one that has it

Answer (score 1):

These two code files contains examples: https://github.com/usethesource/rascal-language-servers/blob/main/examples/pico-dsl-lsp/src/main/rascal/lang/pico/LanguageServer.rsc and https://github.com/usethesource/rascal-language-servers/blob/main/rascal-lsp/src/main/rascal/demo/lang/pico/LanguageServer.rsc

Roughly, if you register a `summarizer` you get called on ever save, than you have the option of typechecking it. I just checked the code, the `builder` is currently not hooked-up yet. But the code you have for the `checkAliases` can be rewrittten to return the `Summary` adt.

Comment: Thanks Davy I have looked at the link I can't find the Syntax definition for the Pico Grammar because I can't figure out where /IdType came from. I will like to understand how to write a summarizer for my own Grammar. I am using the Aliases Grammar in TypePal example. Thanks once again.

Comment: @BenniKatchy it came from this module `import lang::pico::\syntax::Main;` which is part of the rascal base project. https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/blob/main/src/org/rascalmpl/library/lang/pico/syntax/Main.rsc also documented here: https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Library/lang/pico/syntax/Main/

Comment: I've succeeded in writing a Summarizer and I'm calling my TypeChecker (which is actually the TypePal Alias example TypeChecker as it is) but I didn’t get any error reporting I suspect it has to do with how I wired it. How do I marshal the result into a Summary. here is the code.
 
  `model = aliasesTModelForTree(input); // your function that collects & solves
  types = getFacts(model);`
 
I was just going through all the examples I could find to understand how to correctly implement a full-featured Rascal DSL in VSCode. Thanks

Comment: The Tmodel has `.messages` field that you can take out  using getMessages, and then store that directly in the Summary which also has messages. It's a matter of passing the information from one wrapper to the other wrapper.

Comment: Thanks @Jurgen and @Davy, I finally figured out how to marshal a TModel into a Summary, here is my code snippets this could save someone else the pain.

   `TModel model = aliasesTModelForTree(input); 
    messages = {*getMessages(model)};
    return summary(l,
        messages = {<message.at, message> | message <- messages},
    );`

Now I get error reporting working fine.

Comment: Excellent! Why don't you post your own answer and we'll upvote it. I'll leave this answer here for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out how to marshal a TModel into a Summary. Here is the code snippet:

```
Summary aliasesSummarizer(loc l, start[Program] input) {
    pt = parse(#start[Program], l).top;
    TModel model = aliasesTModelForTree(input); 
    definitions = model.definitions;
    return summary(l,
        messages = {<message.at, message> | message <- model.messages},
        references = {<definition, definitions[definition].defined> | definition <- definitions}
    );
  }
```

Thanks to @Davy and @Jurgen for their help. I hope this helps someone else.